# Passing variables between tkinter frame classes in Python

Tags: python, class, variables, tkinter

I have two frame classes and I want them to have common variable, which changes its value while program is running. I have seen some similar threads, but I do not understand how should I do it in my case. My program consists of three files: one stores gui code and runs program (gui.py), second stores first frame class(frame_1.py), and third stores second frame class(frame_2.py). Gui consists of these two frames and button on the bottom. Frame1 on initial has two empty entry fields, both in one row. There is a button in frame_2 which adds another row of entry fields into Frame1.

gui.py

```
import customtkinter
from frame_1 import Frame1
from frame_2 import Frame2


class YfinanceGUI:
    def __init__(self, app):

        self.app = app

        self.frame_1 = Frame1(self.app)
        self.frame_1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.frame_2 = Frame2(self.app, self.frame_1)
        self.frame_2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.print_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, command=self.print_row)
        self.print_button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def print_row(self):
        print(f"Current row: {roww}")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
running = YfinanceGUI(app)
app.mainloop()
```

frame_1.py

```
import customtkinter

class Frame1(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.entry_1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=1 + roww, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry_2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1 + roww, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

frame_2

```
import customtkinter


class Frame2(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, frame_1, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, command=self.add_row)
        self.button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.frame_1 = frame_1

    def add_row(self):
        self.entry_1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.frame_1)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=1 + roww, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry_2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.frame_1)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1 + roww, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

As you can see there is *roww* variable in all three files, but I do no know where to define it and how to do it.

Comment: Your code references `roww` in several places but you never define it. Is that the variable you want to share?

Comment: Yes. Sorry but I accidently deleted end of my post. Edited now

Comment: The easiest I can think of is to create a simple class containing `roww` which you pass around to YfinanceGUI, Frame1 and Frame2. Basically instead of passing a value, you pass a reference to the value. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: I think that `add_row()` should be defined inside `Frame1` instead, and `roww` can simply a class variable in `Frame1`.

Comment: @PatrikGustavsson could you show me an example of how this class should look like and how `roww` would be passed to other classes?

Answer (score 0):

You could use dataclasses:

data.py:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class C:
    a: int       # 'a' has no default value
    b: int = 5   # assign a default value for 'b'
```

testdata.py:

```py
import data

print(data.C.b) #Prints 5
data.C.b = 3 #Change value in other file
print(data.C.b) #Prints new value of 3
```

You can rename the variables, filenames and classname.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a class which contains the data you require and then pass the instance to all classes that needs them, then it will work. This will essentially create a reference to the data instead of just passing the value of the data. Below is an example:

frame_data.py

```py
class FrameData:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.roww = 0
```

Usage

```py
from frame_data import FrameData

class UserOfFrameData:
    def __init__(self, frame_data: FrameData) -> None:
        self.frame_data = frame_data
    
    def increment(self):
        self.frame_data.roww += 1
        print(self.frame_data.roww)

data = FrameData()
first = UserOfFrameData(data)
second = UserOfFrameData(data)
first.increment()
second.increment()
```

The code prints 1 then 2, which means they share the data. You could use dataclass as well, but I tend to just implement a normal class. One difference between dataclass and normal class is how the value of the class variable transfers to the instance value.

If you know you will only need one roww variable for your whole program then you can skip creating an instance and use the example that @mrblue6 suggested.